# PHP Script that'll transfer every request and parameters

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to make something kind of fuzzy today :)

I'd like to create some PHP script / .htaccess to execute every request made to the file (I will redirect every request with .htaccess on my PHP script).

So the script should contact another server with those requests and return the content. My main goal is make it act like a hosts file. I'd send the request with all the parameters, making the other think I'm coming from that very host.

I do this because I can't modify any hosts file on my development server nor on my local workstation. So I'd redirect every request to my development server to my local workstation (on which I installed apache2).

**The main questions are: How would you do so? Do you think the php/htaccess combo is okay? How would I identify as the current host to the other server?**

I guess it's clear enough :) Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: In other words, you're creating a proxy. Why use PHP when there's plenty of free/open-source proxies available already?

Comment: Its not clear what you're expecting as an answer - do you think we're going to write it for you?

Comment: I wanted only some advice and tips on how you would do so, I'm able to write it myself thanks :)

Comment: " I'd send the request with all the parameters, making the other think I'm coming from that very host." - that is going to be impossible: You won't be able to fake the client's IP address. Also, many Ajax based, Flash based, session based applications aren't going to work at all using this method. It won't be possible to replicate `hosts` functionality 1:1 in PHP.

Comment: Then, which language would you take? I can use Perl, Ruby, PHP, Bash, etc...

Comment: @Tom none of them will work for this. They all operate on a level that can't replicate the functionality of a hosts file. All these languages can only make a request on your behalf, and return the results. You would need root access to your server to set up a proper proxy, e.g. using Apache's `mod_proxy`. That will make requests look like the real thing to the client, but even this will not be able to give the remote party your client's IP address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Marc B says, you are looking to build a Proxy. Due to its nature as an interpreted language, PHP is not the optimal solution for this - using a specialized proxy program / server would be less resource intensive.

That said, if PHP is your only option, there is [phpMyProxy](http://www.phpmyproxy.com/) that might work for you. I haven't used it myself locally, but the feature list and the demo look pretty impressive.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes I want to make a proxy, but a very simple and straightforward one. As I don't have any rights to install software on the servers, I'd like it to be only PHP.

Comment: @Tom then phpMyProxy may be a nice option (unless you want to write it yourself for learning).